# How do I jump to the previous/next modification (relative to the git HEAD) in the current file?

Tags: magit, git, navigation, counsel, avy

How do I jump to the previous/next modification (relative to the git HEAD) in the current file?

Ideally, I like sth like `swiper` that lets me choose to easily jump between modifications.

Comment: I currently use `git-gutter:next-hunk`.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

In a *file-visiting* buffer use <kbd>C-c f p</kbd> to visit the last *blob* that modified it. Once you are in a buffer that visits a *blob* instead of a *file* you can use just <kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>n</kbd> to move through time.

Note that the <kbd>C-c f</kbd> transient prefix (aka "menu") command is only available if you have done `(setq magit-define-global-key-bindings 'recommended)`. Otherwise you have to use the annoying default binding, which is <kbd>C-c M-g</kbd>. See that variable for more information.

A "blob" is the version of a file that is stored in a commit. (This is not a precise definition of "blob", but useful in this context.)